# Best way to configure dependent DynamicModules in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I have been struggling with the best approach to deal with importing Nest modules that have interdependencies within the same scope.

My specific use case is a large monorepo with several microservice apps that need specific configuration/setups of a common set of components (e.g. database, transports, etc...). My intention is to provide a "rollup" module to standardise the configuration process.

The problem is it seems that modules within a modules imports array are totally isolated from one another. Although I could use `@Global`, it defeats the purpose of the module level isolation and frankly feels kinda `@Dirty`.

A simplified version of what I have tried:

```js
@Module({})
export class ChaptersModule {
  static registerAsync(config: IChaptersAsyncConfig): DynamicModule {
    const provider = {
      provide: CHAPTERS,
      useFactory: config.useFactory,
      inject: config.inject || [],
    };

    return {
      module: ChaptersModule,
      imports: [CharactersModule], // <-- another DynamicModule
      providers: [provider, ChaptersService],
      exports: [ChaptersService],
    };
  }
}
```

When that module and its dependency is imported into another module:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    CharactersModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => characterData,
    }),
    ChaptersModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: () => chapterData,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Nest instantiates the CharactersModule twice (once for this top level import and one for the ChaptersModule import), even though *they share the same consuming module scope*. Because the module needs configuring, Nest instantiates without its config provider and I get my new best friend:

```sh
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ChaptersService (CHAPTERS, ?). Please make sure that the argument CharactersService at index [1] is available in the ChaptersModule context.
```

After spending way more time on this than I care to share publicly, the only workaround I can find is to instantiate the CharactersModule and *then* pass it to the dependent module via a `requires?: any[]` property I added to my interface.

```js
// Pre-Configure any dependent modules
export const configured = [
  CharactersModule.forRoot(characterData)
]

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...configured, // include configured modules in module imports
    ChaptersModule.registerAsync({
      requires: configured, // pass configured modules
      useFactory: () => chapterData
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This feels hacky and seems to work but surely I am missing something? Example repo is [here](https://github.com/samuelsweet/harry-potter-and-the-curse-of-the-dependency-injection) (the way I anticipated it to work is in the `broken` branch.

What is the correct way of dealing with scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I've got a Git repo that walks through the steps of how this is achievable with some clever RxJS](https://github.com/jmcdo29/dynamic-module-test), but I'll give a high level overview here as well.

So the idea is that you end up having a couple of RxJS operators and properties to your module class; namely a `Deferred` static variable, a private static `timeout` variable, and a `Subject` variable to hold the module configuration. Then, inside of the `forRoot()` or `forRootAsync()`, before returning the configuration, you end up calling `this.moduleConfig.next(configuration)`. Now, wherever else in the app you need you call `Module.Deferred` and get the RxJS deferred configuration. This `Deferred` is a `race` between the `timeout` and the `subject.pipe(take(1))` which will allow you to get either an error (the configuration wasn't ever called) or the configuration at a later time.

[`@golevelup/nestjs-modules`](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/modules)  has a method for this called `externallyConfigured()` which pretty much takes care of the above for you. I highly suggest giving the repo I linked a read to understand the pattern, then the package I linked a shot to see how much it takes care of.

Comment: Thanks Jay. What about bundles that share resources other than configs (e.g. a DB module)? Am I correct in understanding that a module will only ever share DI scope with direct descendants unless its global?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.

Comment: Fair enough :) I checked out your repo and the golevelup one, at a glance it seemed they were more geared towards sharing configs. Will dig a bit deeper. Thanks for your help!